# What is the maximum length of string that can be prepared

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to insert a `base64` encoded string generated from an image through `pdo_odbc` with prepared statements(pdo) into a `VARCHAR(MAX)` field in SQL Server 2008 R2. The string is not fully inserted and is truncated and it shows only part of image. I am having problems inserting image as small as 14kb, but very small images works just fine.

What is the maximum length of string that can be prepared (if any) and is there any work around?

EDIT:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit_image']))
    {
    $datastring = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $data = base64_encode($datastring);

    $stmt=$conp->prepare("insert into tbl (eid, image_data) values (cast(:id as varchar), cast(:data as varchar(MAX)))");
    $stmt->bindparam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->bindparam(':data', $data);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'sucessfully uploaded';
}
```

Comment: Doesn't oracle provide LOB data types that would be more appropriate for storing images.  Also note that base64 encoding a file adds about 30% to the total size.

Comment: Show the code which you use to make transformation. `VARCHAR(MAX)` can hold up to 2 GB of data.